# Convert a SQL Server database to MYSQL database

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Alright so I want to convert an already exist SQL Server database (2005) to a MYSQL database.

There is nothing extraordinary to be done

The only things I need to achieve is

- Recreate the tables
- Transfer data
- Relationships would be nice but not necessary

No views, no sprocs, no functions.

Any easy way to do this.

Also do you know of any Free DST (Database Synchronization Tool)
which would let me do

- MSSQL to MYSQL
- MYSQL to MYSQL
- MSSQL to MSSQL (I know there is SQL Delta for this - not free though)

Answer (score 2):

have you looked at pentaho's kettle (or pentaho data integration)? http://kettle.pentaho.org/

we use it to copy over and keep in-synch disparate database systems, such as mssql<->mysql, which seems to be what you are asking for.

kettle is even more powerful than that, allowing you to query ldap databases, straight text files, etc...

its diagramming tool is similar in look and feel to microsoft's dts (but more powerful, imho)

Answer (score 1):

[**DBConvert**] is best place to solve your Query.

Download links are:-

http://dbconvert.com/convert-mssql-to-mysql-sync.php?DB=6

Download and Install DBConvert on your computer

After installation you may convert your database from MS SQ L To MY SQL in very easy way...

> > select source for remote connection enter IP of the server
> >     and check connection.
> >
> > Here you see your source connection is conneted
> >
> > Same for the destination create connection.
> >
> > Select table you want to convert in your destination database.
> >
> > After complete the copying process click exit to terminate process.

Here your database converted...

Also you may get discount on the product checl the link...

http://dbconvert.com/gift.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out these tools?

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/migrating-from-microsoft.html

Comment: I think this is now: http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql_wp_mssql2mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the correct SQL Mode in MySQL, the [MSSQL setting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html) sounds good to me. With this setting, MySQL works pretty well with ANSI SQL, T-SQL looks like ANSI so you will be fine.