# How can I merge a MS SQL Server database to a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a Microsoft SQL Server database and I want to restore that database to MySQL.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a SQL Server database to MYSQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531578/convert-a-sql-server-database-to-mysql-database)

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917081/how-to-export-ms-sql-database-to-mysql

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by installing MySql Migration tool kit.
After that follow below steps.
[image]